# Get span inside a class using WebDriver and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to scrape the name of a person inside a a span.
This span is inside a class.

Follow the HTML:

```
<div>
<a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/goutham.pullela?ref=br_rs">
<span>Goutham Pullela</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I am trying using `find_elements_by_class_name` and then get the `attribute`, but `span` is not an `attribute`. I don't have a identification for this `span`.

```
contacts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_32mo')

for contact in contacts:
    name = str(contact.get_attribute('span'))
    print(name)
```

Comment: Can you provide the source url? That'd help.

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a CSS selector, and then print the `text` attribute of the `span` element:

```
contacts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('._32mo span')
for contact in contacts:
    print(contact.text)
```

Comment: Sure, I voted but I am new here so I need 15 point to evaluate my vote ok?

Comment: Hi Cody, now I am struggling to get the link: 'href="https://www.facebook.com/goutham.pullela?ref=br_rs'

Answer (score 1):

```
# First we login into Facebook using:

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
email = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
email.send_keys("email@domain.tld")
passwd = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
passwd.send_keys("MyP@$$w0rd");
passwd.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Then We can search and retrieve the name list:

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/search/283544874786/likers?ref=about')
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class, '_32mo')]")
for y in x:
    print(y.text)
```

---

```
Goutham Pullela
Avvaru Srinivasa Rao
Sanjay Bhushan
Ayurveda
Rachit Raj Ias
Anindita Sarkar (Rimi)
Sheela Arora
Padmapriya Rajesh
Manavi Singh
Sanaya Joshi
Kritika Singh
Nikhita Singh
Revathi
Sejal Budholiya
Devi Priya
Rashi Bhatia
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do is, Inspect Element, then in the console top left corner, use the arrow marker and click on Goutham Pullela, then you will see it highlighted on the console. Copy that xpath and use `name = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('[paste xpath']).text` `print(name)`

Comment: but the xPath is dynamic, changes and does not follow a sequence

Comment: @MarceloGazzola XPath is as flexible as css. I‘ll show you in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an comment: Xpath is very flexible too:

```
contacts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='_32mo')]/span")

for contact in contacts:
name=contact.text
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented in 3 lines-

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "_32mo"]')

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

*Why to do this?*

The solutions given above work, although I would prefer the usage of xpath as it fetches all the values in the span of the same class present on the webpage independent of its nesting.